# Compiling HTML body for mail in c#

Tags: c#, asp.net, email, smtp

I am using the following codes for users to send me a quote to my email.

```
    using System.Net.Mail;

    MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
    mail.From = new MailAddress(Email.Text);
    mail.To.Add("my yahoo email");
    mail.Subject = "Requested Quote From my site";
    mail.Body = "<br /><b>Primary project type:</b> " + ProjectTypeRadio.SelectedItem.Text + "<br /><b>Interested In:</b> " + InterestedCheck + "<br /><br /><br /><br /><b>PRODUCT DETAILS:</b><hr />" + Electric + HotWater + PoolHeating + SpaceHeating + "<br /> + "<br /><b>Message:</b><br /><hr /><br />" + txtMsg.Text + "<br /><br />";

    SmtpClient smtp = new SmtpClient("smtp.mail.yahoo.com");
    smtp.Send(mail);
    Response.Redirect("Thanks.aspx");
```

Web.Config

```
<system.net>
<mailSettings>
  <smtp>
    <network host="smtp.mail.yahoo.com" port="995" userName="my yahoo email" password="Password" />
  </smtp>
</mailSettings>
```

**PROBLEM:**
I am recieving the mail in my yahoo account but the message is not formated instead its showing all the HTML tags i.e.

Can anyone please check my code and point my mistake or guide me a solution, it will be a big favor, thanks.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.isbodyhtml.aspx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can set `mail.IsBodyHTML = true`

Also, depending on what you're sending you may want to use [AlternateViews](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.mail.mailmessage.alternateviews.aspx) to send both plain text and text/html variations.

Comment: I tried madding mail.IsBodyHTML = true; but i get an error saying System.Net.Mail.MailMessage does not contain a definition for it.

Comment: thanks pjumble, you solved my problem ... once again big thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

you must set `BodyFormat`
`mail.BodyFormat = System.Web.Mail.MailFormat.Html;`

Comment: `System.Web.Mail` is deprecated in favor of `System.Net.Mail`.